# Webmail background image for windows outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, background-image, html-email

I know that **background-image** is not allowed in windows outlook you can check it bellow:

```
background-image: url(image);
```

[CSS Support Guide for Email Clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Also **background tag** is not readable for windows outlook :

```
background="image"
```

Is there other way to put image under some content?

Answer (score 0):

https://backgrounds.cm/ is your best friend for this.

Outlook needs to use VML to render background images. Content can be built on top of that as normal.

Comment: This is really the best answer, because it is a fantastic tool for doing just what you want it to.

Comment: Did you try "A single table cell" option from the URL above? Also please paste a little code in your original post so we can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

While [backgrounds.cm](https://backgrounds.cm/) is a good resource that covers a lot of bases, I don't think Campaign Monitor updates it and it's gotten out of date.

---

Try using VML code like this:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
   <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style="behavior: url(#default#VML); display: inline-block; position: absolute; width: 640px; height: 300px; top: 0; left: 0; border: 0; z-index: 1;" src="http://media.lt02.net/1/Users/28501/Emmet/background.jpg" />                             
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; width: 640px; height: 300px; top: 0; left: 0; border: 0; z-index: 2;">
    <v:fill opacity="0%" style="z-index: 1;"/> 
    <div>                       
    <![endif]--> 

        Table Contents

    <!--[if gte mso 9]>   
    </div>
    </v:fill>
    </v:rect>
<![endif]-->
```

The main difference between this and the standard VML Background Image is that instead of a `<v:shape>` we're utilizing `<v:rect>` and filling that with a  with 0 opacity. VML like this has been used for repeating background images, but it also works here.